# How can I delete Intellij's local history for a single file?

Tags: history, intellij-idea

I used IntelliJ to edit some external keys that shouldn't be stored on this machine, and so after reverting the changes, I want to delete the history (which contains the keys). Can that be done for a single file?

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: @costa Noooooooope : (

Answer (score 5):

Didn't find a way to delete a single file, only the entire local history.

> On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart IntelliJ IDEA or both.
>
> Warning! Cleaning out the system caches, keep in mind that:
>
> - It results in clearing the local history.
>     To avoid losing data, check in the changes to your version control system before invalidating caches.
> - Causes a complete rebuild of all the projects ever run in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA.

See details [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Comment: Does not clear the local history. At least not on my latest version. So this is not a solution at all.

Comment: @Zordid I believe this answer worked in the past, but I'm not sure. Anyway, it doesn't work for me either with the current version. See my other answer for a solution that works with IntelliJ 2019.2.

Comment: This is the documentation for the latest version: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-projects.html
Important: 

    Files will not be deleted until you restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to delete the local history of a single file either, but there is a retention period for the local history.

You can disable it by setting it to 0. When you restart afterwards the history will be empty. You can then restore the retention period if you like.

> By default, Local History is configured to store revisions for the
>   last 5 working days (that is, days when the file was modified). Change
>   the retention period of Local History﻿
>
> ```
> On the Help menu, click Find Action or press Ctrl+Shift+A.
>
> Find and open the Registry editor.
>
> Modify the value of the localHistory.daysToKeep parameter.
>
> Click Close and restart IntelliJ IDEA for the changes to take effect.
> ```
>
> If you want to disable Local History completely, set the retention
>   period to 0.
>
> Alternatively, you can pass the localHistory.daysToKeep parameter as a
>   Java property by configuring JVM options. For example, to set
>   retention to 30 days, add the following line to the JVM options file:
>
> -DlocalHistory.daysToKeep=30

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#retention

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `LocalHistory` file will remove the history:

MacOs:
`~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.3/LocalHistory`

Windows:
`C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\LocalHistory`

Linux:
`~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.3/LocalHistory`